# Styling md-no-float placeholders

Tags: css, angular-material

Normally, doing this takes care of a placeholder styling:

```
md-input-container[md-no-float]> input::-webkit-placeholder {
    color: #eee;
}
```

Well...not in angular material, I'm assuming? Does anyone know how to get around this? I have a input field with this HTML

```
<md-input-container class="form-group search" md-no-float>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter keyword...">
    <span class="ti-icon ti-search"></span>
</md-input-container>
```

The text in it is naturally black by default but the website is dark. I need the placeholder to be white.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. It's `::webkit-input-placeholder`, not `::-webkit-placeholder`.

Cross browser:

```css
md-input-container[md-no-float] ::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: #eee}
md-input-container[md-no-float] :-moz-placeholder {color: #eee}
md-input-container[md-no-float] ::-moz-placeholder {color: #eee}
md-input-container[md-no-float] :-ms-input-placeholder {color: #eee}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks buddy. I did have to add !important to it though. My guess is angular material already has this css. But the browser inspector doesn't show me where.